# Program stops for some reason, while executed via init.d, but not in nohup call

Tags: sysvinit, autostart

I have created my own heat-control circuit on my raspberry pi, that controls pumps of my home-heating system.

The program is executed each time, Gnu/Linux starts (I put the program into `init.d` and made it executable). After each restart, the program is running (checked it via `pidof program`. However, for some reason, the program stops some when, and I don't know why. After I start the program using the following command:`nohup sudo myProgram`, the program runs for days. I was just wondering why, and how I can check the reason why the program stops the other way around (init.d).

Furthermore, would it be more reasonable to start a script via `init.d` that starts the program using `nohup`?

Comment: Does it also stop randomly under nohup, or did nohup fix the problem? Or do you simply want the init process to restart your program for  you automatically? Or is you actual question about why your program stops?

Comment: If I log in and start the program with `nohub sudo program`, it will run till the rasperry is deconnected from the power supply; so no stop. However, I want that the program starts after a restart (e.g., power supply is canceled and repowered). Thus, the random stops via the start of init.d has to be fixed

Comment: Programs sometimes halt when using stdout but they don't have it. Try to start it redirecting stdout and stderr into a file. If it doesn't halt, it was missing stdout/stderr. If it does you can read in the redirected output what happened.